# LOOP and COUNT in a SELECT statement SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a view with these columns

[image]

and i want to extract this data

[image]

i am doing it in SQL Server manually in several steps and i want to automate it so that i can run a select statement directly from a macro and save it in excel file. 
Here is what i am doing

```
select distinct 
CASE 
WHEN Userid ='jsolar' THEN 'Jack Solar'
WHEN Userid ='jkrcmarikova' THEN 'Jana Krcmarikova'
WHEN Userid ='lfialova' THEN 'lucia fialova'
WHEN Userid ='zsnopkova' THEN 'zuzana snopkova'
END AS [User Name]
, Region
from [SC].[vw_X86_Orders_By_UserID_GAMMA]
order by Region, [User Name]
```

Then i copy the result in excel file and run other queries for each user

```
SELECT Count ( DISTINCT [Order Number]) 
FROM [SC].[vw_X86_Orders_By_UserID_GAMMA]
where Userid LIKE 'jsolar'
AND Region LIKE 'CENTRAL'
and [Order Entry Date] = '2016-10-27'
```

i save this result in number of distinct order number. Then i run this query

```
SELECT Count ( DISTINCT CONCAT ([Order Number], [Line No])) 
FROM [SC].[vw_X86_Orders_By_UserID_GAMMA]
where Userid LIKE 'jsolar'
AND Region LIKE 'CENTRAL'
and [Order Entry Date] = '2016-10-27'
```

I save this result in number of distinct order number concatenated with line no. And i repeat the same for each user

At the end it should be something like this in Excel

[image]

Is there a way how to do this in one select statement to loop each user and count for all users at the same time ? Thank you very much.

Comment: You want region, userid, count of ordernumber, and count of order number with line number?

Comment: I would think so... Where do you have the names of the users stored?

Comment: @esquire Yes, for every user and every region i count how many distinct orderNumber and how many distinct concat(orderNumber, lineNumber)

Comment: @xQbert, the names i don't have it stored in the view, i have it just on paper.

Comment: You should consider saving the names in a separate table, if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I really don't think you need a "LOOP". SQL operates best in set based operations returning recordsets with many rows.  So we need to treat [SC].[vw_X86_Orders_By_UserID_GAMMA] as an entire set and simply update the case statement to translate all users names (assuming you have to have them, or you could do a `vlookup` on the userID in excel after the fact)

I think what you're really after is the `count(distinct column)` in combination with a `group by on userID and region`.

Based on comments I think you would need to amend the case statements in the select and group by to contain the translation for all the users.

I think there's too many unknowns to provide a 100% correct response but here's a shot across the bow..

```
SELECT CASE WHEN Userid ='jsolar' THEN 'Jack Solar'
            WHEN Userid ='jkrcmarikova' THEN 'Jana Krcmarikova'
            WHEN Userid ='******' THEN '**** *******'
            WHEN Userid ='****' THEN '***** ****' END AS [User Name]
, Region
, count(distinct [Order Number]) as cntDistinctOrders
, count(Distinct concat([order Number], [Line No]) as cntDistinctOrderLines

FROM [SC].[vw_X86_Orders_By_UserID_GAMMA]

WHERE [Order Entry Date] = '2016-10-27'
 -- and Region = 'CENTRAL'  don't think you need this the group by handles same names in different regions keeping them distinct and counts seperate.

GROUP BY CASE WHEN Userid ='jsolar' THEN 'Jack Solar'
              WHEN Userid ='jkrcmarikova' THEN 'Jana Krcmarikova'
              WHEN Userid ='******' THEN '**** *******'
              WHEN Userid ='****' THEN '***** ****'
              END
, Region

ORDER BY [User Name], Region
```

To put this in plain English...

You want all the usernames and regions for each user in the [SC].[vw_X86_Orders_By_UserID_GAMMA] schema.table showing the distinct count of orders and order lines for a specific date.

If you can use a Vlookup in excel for the names you could getaway without the case statements and all that extra code..

```
 SELECT UserId [User Name]
    , Region
    , count(distinct [Order Number]) as cntDistinctOrders
    , count(Distinct concat([order Number], [Line No]) as cntDistinctOrderLines
FROM [SC].[vw_X86_Orders_By_UserID_GAMMA]

WHERE [Order Entry Date] = '2016-10-27'
 -- and Region = 'CENTRAL'  don't think you need this the group by handles same names in different regions keeping them distinct and counts seperate.

GROUP BY CASE UserID
, Region

ORDER BY [User Name], Region
```

--note because the group by executes before the select statement, we have to group by the USERID and not the alias name of [User name]

Comment: Thank you very much. I was trying from hours how to make it without success. Very grateful for you.

Comment: I think you need to spend some time understanding the `GROUP BY` clause and the concept of aggregation.  It's the only piece you were really missing.  Also think of the data in terms of data sets, not row by row; also if the names are in an excel sheet that you can use Vlookup on, Id use the VLookup after the data extract and avoid the case statement entirely.

Comment: If this is a production system, the names are likely in a table or view elsewhere in the system, you just need to find them; possibly by looking at foreign key relationships to see how the USERID relates back to another table possibly containing the name.